# Android library to match gesture against pattern?

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition

Is there a library for Android to do pattern matching against gestures? For example, how to detect that the user swiped a square, a circle, a heart or a star?

Where can I post this question if StackOverflow is not the right place?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but Android has a built-in functionality for this: [GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html). Basically it's a `View` which can be drawn over other one, and it can recognize previously defined gestures. [Google Gesture Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch) uses this for example.

Comment: You can also have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html